# Where should i put a logic that is going to be used in many command/query handler?

Tags: nestjs, cqrs

So I have a method that receives an array of ids of a given entity in our database, I search in the db for those ids, and the ones that were not found I store them in DB, after that I return an array of those entities containing the ones that were already created and the new ones.

Since this entity has relations with a diversity of other entities, this logic is expected to be consumed by many command/query handlers, where should I put this logic?

- Create a service file that will be imported and called from each
  domain query/command handler?
- Create a command-handler doing this logic and call this
  command-handler from the other hanlders ( i think this is an
  anti-pattern right? )?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely create a class which encapsulates your logic and inject this class in the command/query handlers.

At first glance, maybe creating a repository class for this entity would be great too, you could encapsulate this logic there.